# error c2007: #define syntax // invalid syntax at a comment block?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

My current problem is that my program wont compile eventhough it did 30 mins ago.

I reverted everything to normal and my compiler shows the error message `ui.h(62): error C2007: #define syntax`. But at line 62 is no code at all because there is an comment block.

I tried to rebuild and clear the solution but nothing works. I use three types of defines.

```
#define DEFAULT_PATH        "C:\\"
#define IMG_Y               35
#define TXT_COLOR       0x323232
```

Edit:  Added code

```
#define IMG_WIDTH           448
#define IMG_HEIGHT          342 
#define IMG_X               96
#define IMG_Y               35

#define DEFAULT_PATH        "C:\\"



/*
 *  Requests a path to save the image at from the user
 */

void function(std::string& file_path) 
{
std::cout<<"Test"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example with the problem ?

Comment: This lacks a [mcve].

Comment: Or at the very least the actual code that causes this error (lines 60-65 for example).

Comment: i added a the specific part where it crashes

Comment: What's that single backtick after the comment?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it was a typo, thank you!
even if i clear the whole file and try to compile the empty file it shows the same error in this file

Comment: `ui.h` might be a generated header. Qt?

Comment: @vahancho No, i wrote it, its for usage with cvui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you have a `#define` without an identifier after it.

Search your code for a dangling `#define`.

Could be a comment after `#define` as well:

```
#define //DEFAULT_PATH
```

Comment: I already thought about this and obviously searched and just re-searched my files for a stray `#define` but there aren't any.
I even removed the comment so that regular code is at line 62 but it still says that there is an `#define syntax` error

Comment: I even cloned the previously working code. But it seems like my compiler seen this error once and doesnt register any code changes after that because it keeps getting stuck at line 62 no matter what i change before and after it

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example, otherwise this is just guessing. Make sure you are actually compiling what you think that you are compiling.